# android cmake undefined reference to properties defined in libuv headers

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk, libuv

there is a source code which is built fine (using cmake) for my host platform but when i target android(using android studio cmake) on the same platfrom it gives me the following errors:

> Error:error: cannot find -l[/root/libuv-1.x/out/cmake/libuv.a]
>
> Error:error: cannot find -lpthread
>
> Error:(49) undefined reference to 'uv_default_loop'
>
> Error:(84) undefined reference to 'uv_fs_open'
>
> Error:(49) undefined reference to 'uv_now'
> ...

any reference to properties defined in uv headers creates a undefined reference to x error.

this is how i include uv in the project cmake:

```
set(UV_INCLUDE_DIR "[/root/libuv-1.x/include/]")
set(UV_LIBRARY "[/root/libuv-1.x/out/cmake/libuv.a]")
find_package(UV REQUIRED)
include_directories("/root/libuv-1.x/include/")
include_directories(${UV_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

and this is how i compile and link the source code in cmake:

```
add_library(proto-lib SHARED ${HEADERS} ${SOURCES} ${HTTPD_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(proto-lib ${UV_LIBRARIES} ${EXTRA_LIBS})
```

the libuv doesn't seem to be included at all.

how can i fix this?

Comment: String `[/root/libuv-1.x/out/cmake/libuv.a]` is not a correct filename or path. If you want to link with `/root/libuv-1.x/out/cmake/libuv.a`, assign the variable to this path.

Comment: @Tsyvarev it solved the linking issue. thank you.